# Why are manual modifications made through SQL Server Object Explorer not shown but new records added are?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Hello I have a console application in which I hard codedly add records. Afterwards I make manual modifications and additions, showing them on the console aswell. The modifications and additions are seen on the console but the actual modification not, while the ones that were added are seen in their new state.

I.E.:

Record 1: "John" modified to "K"
Console application shows that Record 1 has been modified but the name property doesn't show the actual property it shows the old one.
While when I add Record 2 the console shows the actual data of the new record. Why is this?

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome. Type YES to hard codedly add records.)");
            if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("YES"))
            {
                using (var db = new HomeContext())
                {
                    db.Homes.Add(new Home { Owner = "John", Time = DateTime.Now });
                    var count = db.SaveChanges();


                    DateTime old = db.Homes.Max(u => u.Time);

                    Console.WriteLine("{0} records saved to database", count);
                    Console.WriteLine("All records:");
                    foreach (var home in db.Homes)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(home);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("When you've made the manual changes through SQL Explorer GUI on Visual Studio, type YES");
                    if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("YES"))
                    {

                        var records = db.Homes.Where(u => u.Time > old).ToList();              
                        Console.WriteLine("These are the recently made changes:");
                        foreach (var home in records)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(home);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
        }
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

ALL RECORDS:
Home 1 Owner John

**adding modifying manually using Explorer**

**Typing YES**

These are the recently made changes:

Home 1 Owner John
Home 2 Owner newRecord

Comment: Through the SQL Server Object Explorer using the GUI. Clicking "View Data" on the table and manually making the additions. Visual Studio. EF. Code First. C#

Comment: I'm very new to EF and Visual Studio. I click refresh and click enter on the row. Refresh everything but no effect. I definitely leave the row

Comment: Yes I see all changes. The strange things are happening just on the console

Comment: I made the changes. I see them on the tables in the Explorer. Then I performed the query and I see the changes aswell.

Comment: If you add `db = new HomeContext();` before the line that isn't working, does it then work?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! The modified database had to be reloaded into the db variable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change the structure little bit.

While querying the database use new object of DB context